# Add a customized setting into Info.plist using javaFx ant task

Tags: java, macos, javafx, ant

I want to add the following setting in the Info.plist of my application bunld for OSX(Yosemite).

```
<string>Disable App Nap for Express</string>
<key>NSAppSleepDisabled</key>
<true/>
```

We use javaFx ant task to build our application bundle like this:

```
        <fx:application name="${macosx_app}" mainClass="${mainclass}"
              version="1.0">

        </fx:application>

        <fx:bundleArgument arg="mac.CFBundleVersion" value="1.0"/>

        <fx:resources>
            <fx:fileset type="jar" dir="package/macosx/"/>
            <fx:fileset type="jar" dir="lib"/>
        </fx:resources>

        <fx:platform j2se="7.0">                
            <fx:jvmarg value="-Xdock:icon=$APPDIR/Java/${macicon}" />
            <fx:jvmarg value="-Xms128M" />
            <fx:jvmarg value="-Xmx1024M" />
            <fx:jvmarg value="-Dapple.laf.useScreenMenuBar=true" />
            <fx:jvmarg value="-Dcom.apple.macos.use-file-dialog-packages=true" />
            <fx:jvmarg value="-Dcom.apple.macos.useScreenMenuBar=true" />
            <fx:jvmarg value="-Dapple.awt.application.name=${macosx_app}" />
            <fx:jvmarg value="-Dcom.apple.smallTabs=true" />
        </fx:platform>

    </fx:deploy>
```

How can I edit my ant build.xml to add my setting into Info.plist? I read the document of Oracle JavaFX https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/deploy/javafx_ant_task_reference.html and https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/deploy/javafx_ant_tasks.html#CIACDJHC but do not get the useful information. So is there anyone have such experience to add cutomazied setting into Info.plist using javaFx ant task? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

you can add

```
<fx:deploy ... verbose="true" ...>
```

Ant will output sth. like
"Config files are saved to  /var/folders/.../macosx" among other stuff.
There you can find default files like Info.plist that were used while building. You can copy and change them. Ant will also tell you, where to put the customized files to be found by the next build. It's probably sth. like "package/macosx/" in the build folder.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I want to build the whole OSX package during ant build process automatically.

Comment: Ok. But if have have done the step one time (adjusted the default Info.plist and put it into the package/macosx) folder. It stays there and will be reused. So after that step the package will be build automatically by ant with the customized Info.plist.